# Draw a line mixing swing and awt

Tags: java, swing, awt

I've tried to draw a line using Graphics class and then put it inside JFrame object:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

class Window
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private Graphics g;

    public void Window()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(15, 0);
        frame.setSize(600, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }        

    public void DrawCross()
    { 

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(300,0, 200, 0);
        frame.paint(g);  
    }        

}
```

...

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Window.DrawCross(Window.java:33)
    at Main.main(main.java:21)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Where am I wrong and how to fix my mistake? It's impossible to initialise an object of Graphics class that is abstract.

Comment: Being an abstract class I imagine you could just extend it and initialize your own graphics class.

Comment: Reimeus is correct. You might also like to check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Graphics` object has not been instantiated resulting in the `NPE` being thrown.

This approach is just plain wrong. Don't call `paint` directly. Also don't do  any custom painting on a `JFrame`, instead add a sub-class of `JComponent` and override `paintComponent`. Here you will have a readily instantiated `Graphics` object.

[Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 2):

The main error is that it should be `public Window()` without `void`. That is the constructor notation in java. As you called `new Window()` you did not call the public void function Window, hence frame remained null. Hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: Think its actually the `Graphics` object that is `null` which throws the `NPE` as its the first object invoked in `DrawCross` but isnt instantiated anywhere. `frame` is `null` too ofc :)

Answer (score 0):

Working code, created basing on JoopEggen and Reimeus answers:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Window
{
    private JFrame frame;

    public Window()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(15, 0);
        frame.setSize(600, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void drawCoordinateSystem()
    {                
        frame.add( new CoordinateSystem());
    }        

} 



 public class CoordinateSystem extends JPanel 
{
    @Override 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Dimension size = this.getSize();

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(0,size.height/2,size.width, size.height/2);

        g.drawLine(size.width/2, 0, size.width/2, size.height);

    }
}        


class Main 
{    
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
     Window h = new Window();

     h.drawCoordinateSystem();      
    }        

}
```